# Angular2+ Print continuously time on a paragraph

Tags: angular, time

I want to print on a paragraph elapsing time.
This is the function

```
public updateClock() {
    let now = new Date(); 
    this.time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds();
    setInterval(this.updateClock, 1000);
}
```

I used this function on the constructor.
My problem is: the time on the HTML page doesn't change, but I want that time change continuously.

P.s. Time is a variable that I declared at the beginning of the component and this is the HTML code:

```
<p>{{time}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Lambda function when u using setInterval function.

```
  constructor(){
        setInterval(() => this.updateClock(), 1000); 
  }
  public updateClock() { 
      let now = new Date(); 
      this.time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds();
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f4drdz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you, this works! Could you explain me the difference between setInterval in the constructor (and calling the function within) and setInterval within the function? It's a rendering problem? Before i have tried the second and there were problem with the time (sometimes not updating for seconds).

Comment: Earlier each time u call the function new setinterval instance gets created. we only need one instance. so abstract setinterval from the function and call it separately

Comment: Every time a new instance gets creates, angular render the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
public updateClock() {
    setInterval(() => {
      let now = new Date(); 
      this.time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds();
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```